# Adding validation to kendo grid destroy button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

My datasource grabs rows using a controller method (ASP MVC).  I need to set something up so the user can not delete all the rows from a grid, so when the delete button for the final row in the gris id clicked, it needs to realize it is the last, and just say no.  I have been trying to use the DataSource.Total() method and here is where I am at so far:

```
        $("#location-list").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: ds_locationsList,
            sortable: true,
            height: "150px",
            width: "300px",
            editable: "inline",
            columns: [{
                field: "LocationName", title: "Trespassed Location(s)"
            }, {
                command: [{
                    name: "destroy",
                    text: "Delete",
                    click: function(){
                        var rowCount = ds_locationsList.total();

                        if (rowCount < 1) {
                            $("#dialog").dialog({
                                modal: true,
                                buttons: {
                                    Ok: function () {
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        }
                      }
                    }], 
                    width: "110px"
            }]
        });
```

This did not work, I'm thinking I need to get the rowCount from outside the destroy function, maybe in some kind of 'afterLoad'.  I have also tried doing it all outside, but in both cases nothing happens:

```
        $(".k-grid-delete").on("click", function () {
            var rowCount = ds_locationsList.total();

            if (rowCount < 1) {
                $("#loclistval").removeClass("hidden");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Has anyone had to do this? Any suggestions?

================================EDIT======================================

As noted below, I have tried the custom delete function, but it only removing from the client side.  I tried debuggin, but the breakpoint I put in the delete function is never hit, so i must be messing up the call.  Here is my transport code:

```
        transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("JsonPopulateTrespassList", "TrespassOrder")/' + PersId,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST"
                    },
                destroy: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("JsonDeleteLocation", "TrespassOrder")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST"
                    }
        },
```

and my parameter map:

```
         parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
             if (operation == "destroy" && options.models) {
                 var values = {};
                 values["TrespassLocId"] = options.models[0].TrespassLocId;
                 return values;
             }
         },
```

The custom delete:

```
function locDelete(e) {
    var len = this.dataSource.data().length;

    if (len === 1) {
        alert("There must be at least one location.");
    }
    else {
        this.removeRow($(e.target).closest("tr"));
    }
}
```

and the grid code:

```
       $("#trespassed-location-list").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: ds_locationsList,
            sortable: true,
            height: "150px",
            width: "300px",
            editable: "incell",
            columns: [{
                field: "LocationName", title: "Trespassed Location(s)"
            }, {
                command: [{ name: "destroy", text: "Delete", click: locDelete }],
                width: "110px",
            }] 
       });
```

So it removes the row from the client side, but not the server side.  But when I try to debug, the breakpoint on the locDelete function is never hit, so I'm sure what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the [remove](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-remove) event is triggered while the row is being deleted and too late for stopping it.

So, the easiest way is defining a [custom command](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.command) that does the validation.

Define Grid commands as:

```
columns   : [
    {
        command: [
            ...,
            { name: "Remove", click: obDelete }
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

and then define `obDelete` as:

```
function obDelete(e) {
    var len = this.dataSource.data().length;
    if (len === 1) {
        alert("last");
    } else {
        this.removeRow($(e.target).closest("tr"));
    }
}
```

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/bxxqC/

Comment: Thanks OnaBai, I almost have it working.  I assume I a going to have to add an ajax call to the 'else' that deletes the location from the db, right?

Comment: Actually you don't have to. If you define a [destroy](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.destroy) url/function in the DataSource transport it will be invoked when you do [`removeRow`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-removeRow)